# Manually filling additional columns not populated by a nested SP call

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc which calls another stored proc a number of times with different parameters and fills a temp table.

```
--load inactive SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId

--load retailer specific SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId, 2, 1
```

What I want to do is manually populate (hardcode) the SKUType column (this column is not being filled) of the #tmpSKUs table **with each iteration**, so that in the case of Inactive SKUs, it'll populate the table with results and add "Inactive" in the SKUType column. I cannot alter GetAdvancedSKUs as that stored proc has many dependencies.

Here's the full SP code

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetSkuTypes]
@editionId as int,
@isbnNum as nvarchar(20)=null,
@upcCode as nvarchar(20)=null,
@productNum as nvarchar(20)=null
as

IF (@editionId > 0)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #tmpSKUs
(
    SKUId int,
    ProductNumber varchar(255),
    ISBN varchar(255),
    UPC varchar(255),
    Territory varchar(255),
    Format varchar(255),
    Division varchar(255),
    SourceTag varchar(255),
    PictureFormat varchar(255),
    Retailer varchar(255),
    TextAddDetails nvarchar(3000),
    AddDetails nvarchar(3000),
    PackagingLanguage varchar(255),
    EditionId int,
    BluePrintPublishStatus varchar(255),
    SAPPublishStatus varchar(255),
    SKUType varchar(255)
)

--load inactive SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId

--load national single SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId, 1, 1

--load retailer specific SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId, 2, 1

SELECT * FROM #tmpSKUs


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just manually update the column after the inserts?

```
--load inactive SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId

UPDATE #tmpSKUs
SET SKUType = 'Inactive'

--load national single SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId, 1, 1

UPDATE #tmpSKUs
SET SKUType = 'National Single'
WHERE SKUType <> 'Inactive'

--load retailer specific SKUs
INSERT INTO #tmpSKUs 
exec GetAdvancedSkus @editionId, 2, 1

UPDATE #tmpSKUs
SET SKUType = 'Retailer Specific'
WHERE SKUType NOT IN ('Inactive', 'National Single')

SELECT * FROM #tmpSKUs
```

Comment: i have tried that but the execution time goes up significantly vs leaving the column blank (12 seconds vs 5)

Comment: @pnduke How many rows are being returned from each execution of the stored procedure?  That seems like a large increase for what I would assume isn't a massive amount of data... however, without being able to change the stored procedure, I don't know if you'll be able to avoid adding any overhead while changing the results.

Comment: on average about 8K rows. If that's the case, I might have to settle for a manual update. I was hoping there'd be a simple way to do this on the go (as the data gets filled).